# OpenCV - Type 'IplImage' could not be resolved

Tags: c++, opencv, iplimage

I have set up Eclipse to work with OpenCV 2.1.

When I try a simple program, I get the following error:

```
Type 'IplImage' could not be resolved
```

For the following line:

```
  IplImage* img = 0;
```

How can I solve this issue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you sure u tried these:

1. Added the OpenCV core header
2. Included the library?

Visit http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/EclipseOpenCVLinux

Comment: I have followed this tutorial: http://carrierfrequency.blogspot.com/2010/02/setting-up-opencv-20-in-eclipse-on.html, and don't know what is missing. Thanks

Comment: I have now used this updated version of the tutorial, but with opencv 2.3: http://carrierfrequency.blogspot.com/2011/05/opencv-22-in-windows-using-eclipse-ide.html, and still have the same problem. I'm trying to run the code at this page: http://www.cs.iit.edu/~agam/cs512/lect-notes/opencv-intro/index.html under 'Example C Program'. Thanks

Comment: oh yeah.. i think you forgot 
    using namespace cv;

Comment: I'm still having the same issue.

Comment: If you hv problem compiling samples\c\, then you might have library linking problem or din include the opencv header in project.

Comment: How can I include the opencv header. I'm kind new to this. Thanks

Comment: In the Project Explorer tab, right click and select Import... Click on General->Existing Projects into Workspace

    click the Next> button.

    Browse for you ~/opencv/trunk/eclipse_opencv directory. Click OK

    Click the Finish button. You should see this project in your Project Explorer tab

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue for real, and not by forgetting to code or include something (code worked fine in MSVC)

I compared the `.cproject` files from the Hello World project and my own project, and (apart from lots of identifier numbers being different) there were a lot of additional lines. I closed the project, removed those additional lines in an editor, reopened the project, followed carrierfrequency's steps again, and it worked.

At least so I thought. All compiler errors are gone, but now I'm getting lots of linker errors, all about symbols found inside OpenCV itself. It seems the linker cannot find `__exchange_and_add` in `cxoperations.hpp` even though the GUI finds it: when I Ctrl+click on it, it takes me to `bits/atomicity.h`, which *is* properly included in `cxoperations.hpp` (but uses a namespace, which isn't used).

I solved this by changing the symbols `__GNUC__` from 3 to 4 and `__GNUC_MINOR__` from 4 to 0.
It seems Gnu C++ 3.4 doesn't use a namespace, and 4.2 and up use another include (`ext/atomicity.h`) which I don't have, so I arbitrarily chose 4.0.

Project Properties -> C/C++ General -> Symbols

Use **ADD** to change the two symbols, even though they already exist. Using Edit on them just removes them in my version of Eclispe.